# How to update a tab value in JSON using robot framework

Tags: json, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework to update a value in JSON.
Here is my code,

```
&{data}    Load JSON From File    data_mail.json
Update Value To Json    ${data}    $..RecipientEmailName.additionalProp1    ab.fe@abc.com    
Update Value To Json    ${data}    $..SubjectParameters    ["Country","29625","COCA COLA COMPANY"]
```

Here is what I want

```
> {"RecipientEmailName":{
>      "additionalProp1" : "ab.fe@abc.com" }, "SubjectParameters": ["Country","29625","COCA COLA COMPANY"], ...
```

Here is what I have (there are extra " around the tab which makes my code not working)

```
> {"RecipientEmailName": {"additionalProp1": "ab.fe@abc.com",
> "SubjectParameters": "[\"Country\",\"26925\",\"COCA COLA COMPANY\"]",
> ...
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
Update Value To Json    ${data}    $..SubjectParameters    ["Country","29625","COCA COLA COMPANY"]
```

You are setting the value to the literal string `["Country","29625","COCA COLA COMPANY"]`, *not* to a list with four values.

If you want to set the value to be a list, you must do it in two steps. First, create the list, and then modify the json to include the list.

```
@{data}=  Create list  Country  29625  COCA COLA COMPANY
Update Value To Json    ${data}    $..SubjectParameters  ${data}
```

Comment: Just make sure `SubjectParameters` already exists in the initial json. Otherwise, it won't add anything, not even when `Add Object To Json` keyword is used (which is sort of funny considering the name). I'd probably try this keyword first and spend like an hour on solving why it doesn't work. I actually did it now and the result is here: https://github.com/robotframework-thailand/robotframework-jsonlibrary/issues/30

Comment: Thanls for your answer, i thought there's were a difference between tab [] and list {};

Comment: @LouGyde: there is a difference when working in json or python or javascript. In a robot test, arguments are treated as strings in most cases.